# GIS data files converting each address to lat/lon in dbf shape data

Tags: orm, gis, geocoding, shapefile

I need Lat/LON from GIS data

I have data files from 
http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/land_own_property.html

given in the format of 
.dbf, .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .shp, and .shx

in the .dbf I see

```
PIN, Shape_area, Shape_len
PARC_CODE   Parcel Polygon to Parcel Point numeric  2  
            and PIN Relationship Code
```

and in the .prj

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-93.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I also know the polygon points for each county

```
polygons points 
Anoka 129139 129138 
Carver 38134 38133 
Dakota 135925 150294 
Hennepin 422976 446623 
Ramsey 149169 168233 
Scott 55191 55191 
Washington 98915 103915
```

and I know the bounding coordinates

```
-94.012 
-92.732 
45.415 
44.471
```

there seems to be tons of software applications for GIS
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software

but what do I need to do?

I want the lat, lon of every house

Is there a library that will do this for me?
What is the data I need?

Comment: I updated code, more info : search internet for "read ESRI shapefile geotools"

Comment: Might be better for GIS.SE.

Comment: If using `geopandas` see [Convert the coordinates of a shapefile in Geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203938/convert-the-coordinates-of-a-shapefile-in-geopandas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to install one GIS software. You can try open-source [Qgis](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/).

Because, firstly your data is not in long/lat (geographic) coordinates. Your .prj part of the shapefile (yes, all .dbf, .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .shp, and .shx files with the same name are one shapefile for GIS) says that the data are in the projected coordinate system NAD 1983 UTM Zone 15N. So, you need to [transform](https://web.archive.org/web/20211006024328/https://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/Coordinate%20transformations/coordtrans.html) your data to geographic system. This you easy can do in GIS, or programmatically by [proj.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20161230000425/http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) library. (In Qgis add the shapefile to the project, then select it in the table of contents, right mouse button and choose "save as...". It will ask you for the target coordinate system.) Note, that you need to decide which geographic coordinates you wish, because your data are in the North American Datum (NAD 1983), but the most common worldwide now is WGS 1984.

Secondly, in GIS you will see your data, are they really points, or maybe polygons. (In case your houses are polygons you will need to get centroids of them, in Qgis menu Vector - Geometry Tools - Polygon Centroids).

Finally, when you really have your houses as points in geographic coordinates, you can get their coordinates, for example using advices from these questions [Get list of coordinates for points in a layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/getting-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-layer-using-qgis) and [How do I calculate the latitude and longitude of points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/calculating-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis).

Besides, there is a good library to work with GIS vector data, [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs), which can be used by many programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will investigate it tonight!

Comment: Well it appears I have the data switched to WGS1984, I was also successful in getting the polygon centroids... when I export as a csv file (per your links with GEOMETRY=AS_XY) I get X,Y points but they are not LAT/LON but in some other numeric range
IF I go to vector->GeometryTools->Export/Add Geometry Layers it also has xy in non lat lon format
I must be missing something....

when I export it shows CRS WGS 84

Comment: I also made sure onthefly reproject was set to on

Comment: In what format do you get the values? It might be decimal degrees, for example not 37d30'00"N, but 37.500000. Try to put your exported points in Google Earth (it uses WGS84) to see if they are on correct places.

Comment: no dont think so... X Y
515253.0454 4955076.852
515170.7898 4955104.935
515080.7608 4955053.276
515136.3851 4955119.496
514500.4295 4955142.842

Comment: STEPS I take Add shp file by dragging change to point centroid delete orinigal data from project go to project properties click onthefly select WGS84 15N click apply,OK right click data in layers pane click properties click general click specify CRS click EPSG:325615 - WGS84 /UTM zone 15N Click OK right click layer save as CSV Format CSV Encoding System CRS Layer CRS WGS 84/UTM zone 15N layer = GEOMETRY=AS_XY I get output as above –

Comment: So, you are getting projected coordinates of UTM zone 15 of WGS84 datum. You need to specify the coord. system after Save as, and select not a UTM zone but the geographic system pure WGS 84.

Comment: What worked for me was saving a shape file as the WGS84 THEN doing a reimport of that file and exporting from the file with the GEOMETRY flag, if I would try and export and do the flag at the same time it doesnt work, but reimporting does... go figure, thanks for you help! this has saved me a ton of time, and QGIS seems like a great product!

Answer (score 1):

The file extensions above show, that the files are in ESRI Shape File format. In Java you could use GeoTools libraries, to read that.

The example below shows the first lines, search Internet for a more complete example.

```
// init shapefile
        File shpFile = new File(fileName);
        if (!shpFile.exists()) {
            LOGGER.fatal(fileName + " does not exist");
        }

        Map<String, URL> connect = new HashMap<String, URL>();
        FeatureCollection collection = null;
        FeatureIterator iterator = null;
        try {
            connect.put("url", shpFile.toURI().toURL());

            DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connect);
            String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
```

Comment: I downloaded the geotools, no clue where to start with it though

Comment: I updated code, more info : search internet for "read ESRI shapefile geotools"

Answer (score 1):

"I want the lat, lon of every house" suggests that what you want to do is the process called [geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding). There are services you can use for that, some free (for limited uses) some not. You could start by looking at the [List of geocoding systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geocoding_systems) to get an idea of where to start. I don't think you want to start by learning GIS or shapefiles, other than to extract the addresses you are trying to geocode.

You could estimate the lat/lon of each house by computing the centroid of each parcel. You could more roughly estimate the lat/lon of each house by calculating the centroid of the bounding rectangle of each parcel. Either of those would require extracting the parcel coordinates. If you are doing that for every house in Minnesota you will processing lots of data. A geocoding service would be cheaper. The [Census Geocoder](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/geocoder.html) might help.